# Как при переходе на один роутер сделать, чтобы переходило на другой?

Tags: javascript

Есть роутер со страницей входа. Пользователь уже вошел, как сделать, чтобы при переходе снова на этот роутер его кидало на основной роутер, допустим на его профиль?

Comment: В ноде же только один роутер…

Comment: судя по принятому ответу, ваш вопрос не имеет отношения к серверу и node.js. нужно изменить метки вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

идеально использовать это в отдельном слое

ты в App.js инициализируешь роутинг

```
  <RouterProvider routes={routes} />
```

в routes

```
const routes = [
    {
        element: (
            <GuardLayout />
        ),
        children: [
            {
                path: '/',
                element: <HomePage />,
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

в GuardLayout проверяешь юзера и если он не авторизован то будет страница регистрации открываться иначе HomePage. но также ты можешь добавить условие при котором если аторизован то место homePage юзер попадет на нужный тебе компанент

```
const GuardLayout = () => {
  

   if (!user.isAuthorized) {
       return <Navigate to="/auth" />
   }


   return <Outlet />
}
```

Comment: точно. Спасибо!

Comment: только этот проект не на реакт)